# nginx/1.12.2 method not allowed on ajax request PHP nested loop function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, nginx, post

I'm using a `PHP` function that calculate duplicates in an array. It is working fine. But only with about 4000 files. If there are more files like 6000 i encounter an `ajax jquery` **error**. 
my `PHP` function:

```
    public function duplicates($results,$options) {
    $duplicates = array();
    $length = count($results);
    $groupNo = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i++) {
        if (in_array($results[$i]['id'], array_column($duplicates, 'id'))) {
            continue;
        } else {
            for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $length; $j++) {
                if ($results[$i]['file_hash'] == $results[$j]['file_hash']) {
                    if ($options[0] === "allFiles") {
                        if (in_array($results[$i]['id'], array_column($duplicates, 'id'))) {

                        } else {
                            array_push($duplicates, array('id' => "", 'text' => "", 'name' => $groupNo + 1, 'file_hash' => "", 'parent_id' => "", 'isGroup' => false));
                            array_push($duplicates, array('id' => $results[$i]['id'], 'name' => $results[$i]['name'], 'size' => $results[$i]['size'], 'creationDate' => $results[$i]['creationDate'], 'modifiedDate' => $results[$i]['modifiedDate'], 'path' => $results[$i]['path'], 'file_hash' => $results[$i]['file_hash'], 'parent_id' => $results[$i]['parent_id'], 'longCDate' => strtotime($results[$i]['creationDate']), 'longMDate' => strtotime($results[$i]['modifiedDate']), 'isGroup' => true));
                            $groupNo++;
                        }
                        array_push($duplicates, array('id' => $results[$j]['id'], 'name' => $results[$j]['name'], 'size' => $results[$j]['size'], 'creationDate' => $results[$j]['creationDate'], 'modifiedDate' => $results[$j]['modifiedDate'], 'path' => $results[$j]['path'], 'file_hash' => $results[$j]['file_hash'], 'parent_id' => $results[$j]['parent_id'], 'longCDate' => strtotime($results[$j]['creationDate']), 'longMDate' => strtotime($results[$j]['modifiedDate']), 'isGroup' => true));
                    } else {
                        if (in_array($this->GetFileType($results[$i]['name']), $options)) {
                            if (in_array($results[$i]['id'], array_column($duplicates, 'id'))) {

                            } else {
                                array_push($duplicates, array('id' => "", 'text' => "", 'name' => $groupNo + 1, 'file_hash' => "", 'parent_id' => "", 'isGroup' => false));
                                array_push($duplicates, array('id' => $results[$i]['id'], 'name' => $results[$i]['name'], 'size' => $results[$i]['size'], 'creationDate' => $results[$i]['creationDate'], 'modifiedDate' => $results[$i]['modifiedDate'], 'path' => $results[$i]['path'], 'type' => $this->GetFileType($results[$i]['name']), 'file_hash' => $results[$i]['file_hash'], 'parent_id' => $results[$i]['parent_id'], 'longCDate' => strtotime($results[$i]['creationDate']), 'longMDate' => strtotime($results[$i]['modifiedDate']), 'isGroup' => true));
                                $groupNo++;
                            }
                            sleep(20);
                            array_push($duplicates, array('id' => $results[$j]['id'], 'name' => $results[$j]['name'], 'size' => $results[$j]['size'], 'creationDate' => $results[$j]['creationDate'], 'modifiedDate' => $results[$j]['modifiedDate'], 'path' => $results[$j]['path'], 'type' => $this->GetFileType($results[$j]['name']), 'file_hash' => $results[$j]['file_hash'], 'parent_id' => $results[$j]['parent_id'], 'longCDate' => strtotime($results[$j]['creationDate']), 'longMDate' => strtotime($results[$j]['modifiedDate']), 'isGroup' => true));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $duplicates;
}
```

some times the function is working fine, but not on big files no of files.

Comment: Can you mention your error please?

Comment: <html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.2</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: is there any kind memory execution issue finction is calling in ajax post

Comment: Are you using Ajax get or post? Also calling ajax on same domain right?

Comment: i am using ajax post and on same domain

Comment: Make sure your method is also accepting the post request, I mean the route of your method.

Comment: ye accepting post request it fails only when no items in array  increases

Comment: Can you increase the execution time? i.e `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

Comment: no  i am not setting i am using timeout 0 on ajax post

Comment: if execution time is not the problem, maybe memory is ;o)